# Laravel Schema Builder partial indexes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-schema-builder

How can I create partial indexes using Laravel 5.2's Schema Builder?

For instance, instead of the query `create index alternate_listing_not_null on listings(alternate_listings_id) where alternate_listings_id is not null` how would I do this with Schema Builder syntax?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.